# Lining up cards in a row dynamically (based on available space)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

I stumbled on this site: http://deweyapp.io/. If you play around with the size of the browser window, you'll see that the cards either drop to the next line or are pushed up to the previous one (depending on the resize action).

How is this accomplished using bootstrap or material design? I can't figure it out, for the life of me.

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cards are in a container `<li>` which has a fixed width and `display:inline-block;`

Comment: This really doesn't help me :) There's no clear way to understand how they got this working. I'm been trying to replicate this functionality for a while but can't seem to grasp the concept.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle to check it out? https://jsfiddle.net/z4bty4xg/
Although your example probably has some extra functionality to keep everything centered in the UL.